# execute a task before shutting down RMI server

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-system

I'm using java RMI to implement a distributed bank system where each server represents a branch with it data stored on its own database
when closing a server/branch , the accounts stored in its database should be transferred to another server/branch 
how to execute the code of this task just before the server is closed
any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe shutdownHook will be good for you.

Example code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    System.out.println("shutdown application");

    }
}));
```

Comment: No it wouldn't. Shutdown hooks are supposed to execute very quickly. This is a terrible idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a shutdown hook 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook